# Javascript Async Functions - Second Function not waiti

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Good Morning Everyone,

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around some asynchronous activities.

What I'm looking to do is grab some data, pass the returned value to a variable, display that information (and do some other functions based on what comes out). This process should be expandable to multiple datasets, such as hourly forecasts, weekly forecasts, fire-hazard info etc. and will be running on an interval.

I've gone through MDN's Promise page along with numerous searching on here for an answer, but it doesn't seem to click.

What I have so far:

```js
let weeklyData;
let pull;

async function pullData(url){
  fetch(url).then(res=>res.json()).then((val)=>{pull=val});
}

function buildDataSets(){
  for(let x = 0; x < pull.properties.periods.length; x++){
    weeklyDataSets[x] = pull.properties.periods[x];
  }

}
```

When called by hand in the console, these resolve correctly. *Pull* comes out as an object, and *buildDataSets()* can run. I imagine that's because there's enough time for *pullData(url)* to resolve.

I need to process the response from *pullData(url)* so I need to assign its return value to an object.

What I can tell, I should be using something in the ballpark of

```js
Promise.resolve(pullData(url))
    .then(()=> buildDataSets());
```

This returns a pending status, and pull remains undefined when *buildDataSets()* goes off. I know that I need to pull the data, wait until fulfilled, then assign the value into *pull* if successful. Then after pull has been assigned call the *buildDataSets()* function. Adding a *.then()* that calls *buildDataSets()* doesn't seem to work either resulting in *pull* to be undefined when it attempts to access values.

Would someone please help explain what I'm missing? I feel like I'm staring at  the answer, but can't see it.

Comment: `pullData` doesn't return the promise from `fetch`.

Comment: `pull=val` consider not doing this. Put `buildDataSets` inside the `then` of `pullData`

Comment: It should be explained in this question: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: @derpirscher it's a promise, it already carries the data. Ferrying the data through a shared (global) variable is a crutch. It's not needed and it's error-prone

Comment: @VLAZ thats correct. But if one says "don't do this" some sort of reasoning would be nice ...

Comment: @evolutionxbox  thats correct. But if one says "don't do this" some sort of reasoning would be nice ...

Comment: @derpirscher I added my reasoning in the second comment. I couldn't find it originally.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping and this discussion! It was helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be returning a value from `pullData` so that others can `await` for it (or access it in the `then` handler). See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

You typically don't set a non-local variable from an asynchronous callback exactly because of what you have mentioned. THe

You probably want `buildDataSets` to also return a Promise.

```
async function pullData(url){
  return fetch(url).then(res=>res.json()));
}

async function buildDataSets(){
  const pull = await pullData('/url');
  const weeklyDataSets = {};
  for(let x = 0; x < pull.properties.periods.length; x++){
    weeklyDataSets[x] = pull.properties.periods[x];
  }
  return weeklyDataSets;
}

async function myMain () {
    const data = await buildDataSets();
    console.log({data});
}
```

Here's the same code without using `await`s, just `Promise` chains

```
function pullData(url){
  return fetch(url).then(res=>res.json()));
}

function buildDataSets(){
  return pullData('/url')
    .then((pull) => {
      const weeklyDataSets = {};
      for(let x = 0; x < pull.properties.periods.length; x++){
        weeklyDataSets[x] = pull.properties.periods[x];
      }
      return weeklyDataSets;
    });
}

function myMain() {
    return buildDataSets().then((sets) => {
        console.log({sets});
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! (my comment got locked)

So I just want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly.

We get the promise with a json value out of pullData.

We assign it to pull with an await so that it resolves in the buildDataSets queue(?) then we can use it to pass its value into weeklyDataSets? Otherwise we're pulling the data and then immediately trying to assign.

Would that be accurate?

Comment: @ChrisGergler I don't understand the question. The point is that you should (almost) never assign a non-local variable in a callback. Returning a promise from a function and using that instead of assigning variables is what you need to do.

I used `await` but could have used `Promise.then` chains. I'll the chains example to the answer

Comment: Ahh, I'm seeing something with it. We have pull.properties (etc) failing to be recognized because those are all functions for the object that I made from pull previously. However now I'm back to square one where I need to access the values of the promise that's passed through but have no access to them. So within my promise, I have the status and the value. I don't know how to access the value without assigning it.

Comment: @ChrisGergler You access he promise value either from the `then` callback, or by using `await`. Assignment to some global function will lead to race conditions and hard to find bugs.

Comment: So, for example, I have:
```js
async function getLocation( long, lat)
{
  //Establish initial local vars and call for the location data.
  let response = await fetch(myloc + long +"," +lat);
  if(!response.ok){throw new Error(response.status)}
  site = await response.json();
}
```
site is receiving an object output. I would instead want to just assign the promise received to site, and then when I need to I put on ```site.then((x)=> { return data });```?

Comment: You seem focused on trying to assign some asynchronous value to a global variable but we're telling you that you should not do that. Doing that is asking for trouble because you have no way to know when that variable will be set.

Comment: Did you go through the linked answers? It sounds like you haven't and you still don't understand how asynchronous programming works in JS but you want to keep using a method we're explicitly telling you not to use (assigning an asynchronous value to a non-local variable). The only safe way to read an asynchronous value is from the callback of a promise (or by using `await`) and properly chain  the promises to ensure everyone is waiting for it to be available before trying to use it. If it's still confusing, ask a more focused question because you have the solution for the problem you posed.

Comment: I explicitly stated that I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: That's why I suggested you ask another question. One that doesn't involve trying to assign to a global variable and accessing the same global variable from a different function. Notice that my solution doesn't assign to non-local variables, it chains them through return values.

Comment: By the way, you may have missed the very beginning of my answer "You should be returning a value from pullData so that others can await for it" If you change `pullData` to `return fetch`, then `Promise.resolve(pullData(url)).then(()=> buildDataSets());` will work as expected though it could be simplified to `pullData(url).then(buildDataSets)`; However, we're explicitly telling you not to do that because it is problematic.

Comment: I definitely did miss that, thank you for highlighting it! I did post a second question, with a bit more breakdown of what I'm attempting to do. Hopefully when I do these adjustments it'll work as I need it and I can just keep going. Thank you for your patience with me!